# Transit visa in Dubai (landing in XNB, leaving via DXB)

Tags: visas, transit, filipino-citizens, uae, dxb

I am arriving in Dubai XNB at 6am from an Etihad flight. Then on 5pm, I am leaving Dubai on a Flydubai flight. Do I need a transit visa? (I'm Filipino so visa is always a constraint whenever we fly outside of Southeast Asia.)

I am asking because i have read conflicting accounts that I can ask for transit visa via Etihad since I am arriving from an Etihad flight.

Comment: XNB and DXB are the same airport! I presume you're actually flying Etihad to Abu Dhabi (AUH) and taking their bus to Dubai Intl bus station (XNB)?

Comment: In any case, I doubt Etihad will arrange a visa for you, because your connecting flight is with another airline.

Comment: @jptokal Isn't XNB the Etihad Travel Mall Bus Station? Isn't that different from Dubai International Airport DXB?

Comment: In fact, you will arrive in Abu Dhabi (AUH). Then a bus will take you to the Etihad Travel Mall in Dubai (XNB). This is some 20 kilometers away from Dubai International Airport (DXB). There is a metro station nearby, from where you can take a direct train to DXB. Note that the metro does not run on Friday morning.

Comment: @user161300 Oops, you're right, I stand corrected -- but can't edit my comment anymore :(

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

As a Filipino citizen you are not eligible for a "[visa on arrival](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/en/global/do-i-need-a-visa/)" in the UAE. Instead, you have to apply for a visa beforehand.

Etihad Airways [helps you to arrange the visa](http://www.etihad.com/en/before-you-fly/visas/). They provide an [online service](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/en-ph/) for this sake.